# If $x^p P(|X|>x|)=o(1)$, then $E(|X|^{p-\epsilon})<\infty$ for $0<\epsilon<p$

Tags: probability, probability-theory

If $p>0$ and $x^p P(|X|>x|)=o(1)$ as $x\to\infty$, then $E(|X|^{p-\epsilon})<\infty$ for $0<\epsilon<p$.

It feels like the assumptions should lead to something like $\sum_n^\infty ((n+1)^{p-\epsilon}-n^{p-\epsilon})P(|X|>n)<\infty$ but I don't see what to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A consequence of Fubini-Tonelli's theorem is that for any non-negative random variable $Y$ and $q>0$,
$$E(Y^q)=q\int_0^{+\infty}t^{q-1}P(|Y|>t)dt.$$
Using this with $q:=p-\varepsilon$ gives the result.

Comment: And shows that the condition $x^p P(|X|>x|)=o(1)$ can be relaxed to $x^p P(|X|>x|)=O(1)$.